# Why node.js is much slower than Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, google-chrome, v8

I've got simple code, that creates a chunk with 16*16*256 boxes of 10 elements array and a bool variable. Method tick increases array elements and changes boolean value for each box in a chunk 100 times.
By measuring time I've got the results:

**Windows x64 node.js 7.4.0:**
1 tick: 102.85
Total time(100): 10285

**Google Chrome 55 on the same machine:**
1 tick: 18.08
Total time(100): 1808

Even underlying snippet is an order of magnitude faster than a Node.
**Snippet:**
1 tick: 22.79
Total time(100): 2279

So, how can I make Node work faster?

```js
(function(){
 class Box {
  constructor() {
   this.data = new Array(10); 
   this.state = false;
  }

  tick() {
   this.state = !this.state;
   for(let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
    this.data[i]++;
   }
  }
 }

 class Chunk {
  constructor() {
   this.data = new Array(256);

   for(let z = 0; z < this.data.length; z++) {
    this.data[z] = new Array(16);

    for(let x = 0; x < this.data[z].length; x++) {
     this.data[z][x] = new Array(16);

     for(let y = 0; y < this.data[z][x].length; y++) {
      this.data[z][x][y] = new Box();
     }
    }
   }
  }

  tick() {
   for(let z = 0; z < this.data.length; z++) {
    for(let x = 0; x < this.data[z].length; x++) {
     for(let y = 0; y < this.data[z][x].length; y++) {
      this.data[z][x][y].tick();
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }



 var c = new Chunk();
 var count = 100;
 var start = new Date().getTime();

 for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  c.tick();
 }

 var end = new Date().getTime();

 console.log("1 tick: " + (end - start) / count);
 console.log("Total time(" + count + "): " + (end - start));
})();
```

Comment: Chrome typically updates V8 often, about every release; what version of node?

Comment: Added version to the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-filling the arrays gives an order of magnitude improvement in node

The only explanation I can give is that the "conversion" of an empty array slot to a "used" slot is more expensive in nodejs - you may find similar speed up by simply "filling" the array from length-1 to 0 in your original code (not quite as much but close)

The major speed up is the pre-fill of this.data in class Box (but that's probably because `this.data[i]++` on an `empty` array item is used 655360 times)

```
(function(){
    class Box {
        constructor() {
            this.data = new Array(10).fill(0); 
            this.state = false;
        }

        tick() {
            this.state = !this.state;
            for(let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
                this.data[i]++;
            }
        }
    }

    class Chunk {
        constructor() {
            this.data = new Array(256).fill(null);

            for(let z = 0; z < this.data.length; z++) {
                this.data[z] = new Array(16).fill(null);

                for(let x = 0; x < this.data[z].length; x++) {
                    this.data[z][x] = new Array(16).fill(null);

                    for(let y = 0; y < this.data[z][x].length; y++) {
                        this.data[z][x][y] = new Box();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        tick() {
            for(let z = 0; z < this.data.length; z++) {
                for(let x = 0; x < this.data[z].length; x++) {
                    for(let y = 0; y < this.data[z][x].length; y++) {
                        this.data[z][x][y].tick();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }





    var c = new Chunk();
    var count = 100;
    var start = new Date().getTime();

    for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        c.tick();
    }

    var end = new Date().getTime();

    console.log("1 tick: " + (end - start) / count);
    console.log("Total time(" + count + "): " + (end - start));
})();
```

> as an aside, your Chunk constructor can be "simplified" to

```
this.data = new Array(256).fill([]).map(item => new Array(16).fill([]).map(item => new Array(16).fill([]).map(item => new Box())));
```

But this does not make any further improvement

I also tried using `.forEach` and/or `.map` where appropriate - but any such change actually slowed down the tick by about 10% in node

Comment: speeds up Chrome too, but they are now about equal! Why would unboxing the mix-typed array (null and numbers) hurt so much more in node?

Comment: Wow! Works about 25 times faster! May be there is another way of creating classes and arrays that can speed it up too?

Comment: I've given you 25x speed improvement (odd, only about 10x on my system, but my `ticks` are 6.4 or so) - but you want more!!! :p